# how to sudo on logon

Tags: mount

I've got entries in `/etc/fstab`, and the command lines to mount a set of windows disks from another system, and it works if I type the commands in a terminal window.

Where and how do I put these so they run just once at logon, with a `sudo` in front of them, but so they don't stop to ask for password?

I'm very old-school UNIX, but new to Ubuntu.  In my day I'd put such in my `.profile` , but if I understand, the `.bashrc` runs for every new terminal window, right?

Comment: What are these command lines, exactly?

Comment: Put the script in a dbus service (run by root). Trigger the dbus service with  a job in ~/.config/autostart

Comment: Sample /etc/fstab entry: 
`//10.0.0.10/CDRIVE /media/asus_c cifs rw,user,exec,noperm,noauto,credentials=/home/larry/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0)`
Sample mount command:
`sudo mount /media/asus_c`  
It all works on the command line, I just want to automate it so it happens everytime I logon

Comment: As you defined option `user` in the fstab, you should not need `sudo`to mount; so just call the `mount`command from your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login`, whichever is defined, or create an appropriate desktop file in `~/.config/autostart/`

Comment: Wow, good deal.  I didn't even think to try without sudo.  Its been a l-o-n-g time since I did any *nix admin and it shows.  Thanks!